# How to check if all packages meet version requirements?

Tags: python, requirements

When running a script in Python interpreter, I want to check if I use the following versions:

```
absl-py==0.1.10
agate==1.6.0
agate-dbf==0.2.0
agate-excel==0.2.1
agate-sql==0.5.2
appnope==0.1.0
```

I can for example do this:

```
if absl-py.__version__ != "0.1.10":
    logging.error("update to version == 0.1.10")
    sys.exit() #
```

And repeat for all other packages. Is there a way to iterate through all the specified packages and raise and error when one if the conditions is not met?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this and define the modules and versions in a dictionary:

```
import pkg_resources

module_versions = {"absl-py":"0.1.10", "agate":"1.6.0"}

for module, v_req in module_versions.items():
    try:
        if pkg_resources.get_distribution(module).version != v_req:
            print(f"{module}, Required Version: {v_req}, Your Version: {v_inst}")
    except:
        print(f"{module} not installed")
```

Comment: This will fail for `absl-py` even if it's installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to check if the packages exist (make sure to create `requirements.txt` first):

```py
with open("requirements.txt") as f:
    packages = f.read().split("\n")
    for package in packages:
        package_name, package_version = package.split("==")
        package_name = "_".join(package_name.split("-"))
        exec(f"""\
try:
    import {package_name}
except ImportError:
    print("{package_name} doesn't exist") 
else:
    if not {package_name}.__version__== '{package_version}': 
        print(f"{package_name} is not up to date")""")
```

Comment: With [`__import__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) you won't have to resort to the unforgivable `exec` curse. Also, package published name does not always correspond to its import name, e.g. `PyYAML` vs `yaml`.

Answer (score 1):

You can receive the list of the installed packages using setuptools' [`pkg_resources`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html):

```
import pkg_resources
package_versions = {
    p.project_name: p.version for p in pkg_resources.working_set
}
```

Now you can iterate through your file and compare the versions in it with those in the `package_versions` dict.